# How to Solve Specific Dependent RV Transformation

Tags: statistics

**This is not a classroom problem. This is a part of my own education.**

Assume we have a random variable $X$ that is iid distributed according to the distribution $p$ that is defined as follows:

\begin{equation}
  p(X=x)=\frac{1}{2(x-1)^2}I_{\left[0,\frac{2}{3}\right]}(x)
\end{equation}

Also, let $n \overset{iid}{\sim} U(3X,2)$.

We wish to determine the transformation:

\begin{equation}
 Y = \frac{n}{n+X}
\end{equation}

This "$2X$" dependency in the $n$ distribution is throwing me off, and I am unsure how to begin this or similar problems. The transformation techniques I use do not involve dependencies such as this.

I attempted to gain some insight using Mathematica with the following script:

[image]

However, it gave me a nonsensical answer:

[image]

Any insight into how to solve this problem correctly would be great!